# Use of positional with two queried arrays, with one not needing to affect positional operator

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to push a comment to my `Class` document collection, which has a list of `lessons`. I want to make sure that the user posting the comment is registered to the `Class` and to do that I have a field `mentors.mentorList` that holds the users that have privilege to post in the `Class`.

```
     Class.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: "5e1baeb07fcee8639cbce2ac", "mentors.mentorList":{ $eq: "5c9ba636347bb645e0865283" } , 
         "lessons._id": "5db221be211d7b68ac8be618" },
        { $push: { "lessons.$.comments": commentObj } },
        { new: true }
      )
```

Which actually is using the matched index in the `mentor.mentorList` of the query (index 0) and updating the `$push` to the `lessons[0].comments`. Is it possible to exclude the `mentors.mentorList` from affecting the positional operator?

Comment: You could swap the arrays in the query and it may work but note this behavior is undefined. You should use positional operator in 3.6 and use named index to target arrays. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with-identifier

Comment: I tried swapping places as well, but it yields the same results. I think it's because in my schema, the "mentors" field comes first.